# How to Compare 10 Integers and get the largest and smallest interger values in a While Loop in Java Issue

Tags: java, algorithm, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to figure how to get the smallest and largest integer values when a user inputs 10 different integer values. I got most of it but, I can't get the smallest value I only get the largest value.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargestAndSmallestValue
{

public static void main ( String[] args )
{


 Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

 int counter;
 int largest = 0;
 int smallest = 0;
 int number;

 number = 0;
 counter = 1;

 while ( counter <= 10)
 {
     System.out.printf(" Enter a Integer: ");
     number = input.nextInt();
     ++counter;

     if (number > largest)
     {
        largest = number; 
     }

     else

        if (number < smallest)
        {
           smallest = number;
        }

 }

 System.out.println("Smallest: " + smallest);
 System.out.println("Largest: " + largest); 

 }
}
```

Comment: So what is smaller than 0?

Comment: You should be able to figure out where the problem is yourself. Read some articles on debugging. Using a debugger to trace the program’s execution is very beginner-friendly in today’s IDEs. Also debug prints are useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two potential problems with your code:

Your initial values for `largest = 0;` and `smallest = 0;` could actually be larger or smaller than your inputs.  For example, none of the numbers 1 - 10 are smaller than 0. You should initialize these variable to extreme values to guarantee that your inputs will set the largest or smallest values when comparing. Something like

```
int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE; //  or other smallest possible input (0)
int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // or other largest possible input (100000000)
```

The next potential problem is in your comparison logic.  Your if-else structure assumes that an input cannot be both the current largest and smallest at the same time.  Consider when the first input is the smallest: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`.  On the first iteration of your loop, `1 > largest` is true, so you never bother to check whether `1 < smallest` which should also be true (if you put in the other fix).  You have two options here:

- Change your condition checking to two separate checks (remove the `else`)
- Set the value of largest and smallest to your first input to get around this corner case.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of setting smallest to 0, set it to the first number that was read as input.

```
boolean firstNum = true; // initialize this to act as a flag
while ( counter <= 10) {
    // your printf and input reading here 

    if (firstNum) {
        smallest = number;
        firstNum = false; // you only need to set the initial value once.
    }

    // your if statements here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your temp variables like this:

```
int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;  //  2147483647
int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // -2147483648
```

The way you are doing it now, if the minimum value entered is 17, but your `smallest` variable is initialized to 0, `smallest` never changes.